# how to make apps minimize to dock?

Tags: cairo-dock, minimize

I installed mac themes for ubuntu 12.04 and cairo dock. I want apps to minimize to cairo dock instead of the unity panel. Before anyone recommends docky, I tried it and it had a lot of bugs. So is there any way by which apps will minimize to caro dock? thank you . Any answer will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm looking for solution to the same problem. I've cairo dock positioned at bottom of the screen and unity launcher on left. Application minimize to the left instead of bottom.